# Corollary **to** Theorem 1.2 or corollary **of** Theorem 1.2?

Tags: terminology, education

I think both ways are possible in English, but should I say

> This is a corollary **to** Theorem 1.2

or

> This is a corollary **of** Theorem 1.2

?

Comment: The second one is clearly more common.

Comment: For me, I usually use the first one.

Comment: "Clearly"? How so?

Comment: The books that I usually read uses the sencond ones.

Comment: I use *of* unless *of* is used in a nearby preposition, in which case I use *to* to avoid repetition. For example, "See the first part of the corollary to Theorem 7 of Chapter 3."

Answer (score 1):

In contemporary U.S. English, "corollary to X" would be (slightly intellectual-sounding) non-math usage, so also in-principle-legit *in* math, while the "corollary of X" is specific U.S.-math-English usage. The only slight bias might be to use "corollary of" because it sounds more typically math-y... ?